# Rust import error

Tags: rust

I have a Rust project made by `cargo init`:

```
dir
 |-src
    |-main.rs
    |-settings.rs
    |-functions.rs
```

I have in `settings.rs`:

```
use ::functions;
```

but at compilation I get an error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `functions`
--> src/settings.rs:3:5
  |
3 | use ::functions;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ no `functions` in the root
```

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what the contents of `main.rs` are, as one example. Ideally, produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org). There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: Also, **please** read [the documentation on modules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch07-00-modules.html) because it covers the basics around this.

Comment: There are also [*numerous* questions with the same error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+is%3Aq+%22unresolved+import%22); have you looked at any of these? It's highly likely that this is a duplicate of one of them.

Comment: of course I read documentations on modules, I don't want to use  [mod functions] because it will search for settings/functions.rs, and it is not i want to.

Comment: it is not a duplication, I've double-checked

Comment: I already created the minimal example, and it is also most complete. I cannot produce that error on rust playground, because it is linking problem

Comment: @Shepmaster, can you give better advise?

Comment: Do your `main.rs` contains `mod functions`?

Comment: @xiaomifanboy Please read the content behind the many links Shepmaster has provided to you. It is rude to request for more advice after you were given plenty of content to improve your question. The question still doesn't look complete enough to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comments, you state:

> I don't want to use [mod functions] because it will search for settings/functions.rs, and it is not i want to

Have you tried that? Assuming you've declared the module correctly ... this is *exactly* what you want.

main.rs:

```
mod functions;
mod settings;

fn main() { 
    ...
}
```

settings.rs:

```
use functions;

pub fn something() {
    functions::some_function_here();
}
```

If this does not work .. then there is something missing from your problem description.

Comment: That is what i looked for! Thank you! But can you explain how does it work? This is really confusing. Also, can I remove [mod functions] from main.rs somehow?

Comment: There's no need to remove functions that have been imported from another module. Unlike say, Python, only functions that you explicitly re-export are available outside of main

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're confusing the role of the root namespace. `use ::functions;` means something slightly different than `use functions;`

Let's consider your project structure:

```
project
├── src
|   ├── settings.rs
|   ├── functions.rs
|   └── main.rs
└── Cargo.toml
```

When you're within `settings.rs`, the other modules are at the same level, so a `use functions;` accesses the `functions` module.

If you do wish to refer to the `functions` module via the root namespace, then the full path looks like this `::project::functions` and the `use` declaration is `use ::project::functions;`.