# Rust imports: split large file into smaller files

Tags: import, rust

I am writing a TUI app in rust to manage some game servers. The application itself works fine but the main.rs file is now over 1k lines so I decided to split it into multiple files to make it easier to work with. Each of the files needs to be able to access the structs and functions in the other files. The split files have the following structure.

```
src \
    main.rs
    render.rs
    ark.rs
    db.rs
```

This is my current Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "ark-manager"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Nan0Scho1ar <scorch267@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
crossterm = { version = "0.19", features = [ "serde" ] }
serde = {version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
chrono = { version = "0.4", features = ["serde"] }
rand = { version = "0.7.3", default-features = false, features = ["std"] }
tui = { version = "0.14", default-features = false, features = ['crossterm', 'serde'] }
thiserror = "1.0"
```

I tried following the documentation I found here.
https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch07-05-separating-modules-into-different-files.html

Which led me to a believe the solution looks something like this.

main.rs

```rust
mod render;
mod db;
mod ark;

pub use crate::render::*;
pub use crate::db::*;
pub use crate::ark::*;

//Main loop etc
...
```

ark.rs

```rust
pub mod ark {
    pub use crate::render::*;
    pub use crate::db::*;

    //Structs, enums etc
    pub enum Event<I> {
        Input(I),
        Tick
    }
    ...
}
```

db.rs

```rust
pub mod db {
    pub use crate::render::*;
    pub use crate::ark::*;


    //DB functions
    ...
}
```

render.rs

```rust
pub mod render {
    pub use crate::db::*;
    pub use crate::ark::*;

    //Render functions
    ...
}
```

I also updated to the references to the things which are now in separate modules

```
//E.G.
if let Ok(_) = tx.send(Event::Tick) {
//Becomes
if let Ok(_) = tx.send(ark::Event::Tick) {
//And
Event::Input(event) => match event.code {
//Becomes
ark::Event::Input(event) => match event.code {
```

But this led to the following errors.

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `Event` in `ark`
  --> src/main.rs:79:45
   |
79 |                 if let Ok(_) = tx.send(ark::Event::Tick) {
   |                                             ^^^^^ could not find `Event` in `ark`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `Event` in `ark`
   --> src/main.rs:216:22
    |
216 |                 ark::Event::Input(event) => match event.code {
    |                      ^^^^^ could not find `Event` in `ark`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `Event` in `ark`
   --> src/main.rs:226:22
    |
226 |                 ark::Event::Tick => {}
    |                      ^^^^^ could not find `Event` in `ark`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `Event` in `ark`
   --> src/main.rs:230:22
    |
230 |                 ark::Event::Input(event) => match event.code {
    |                      ^^^^^ could not find `Event` in `ark`

...
```

After trying to get this to work for some time I decided to see how other people solved this issue and I found a number of answers to questions on stack overflow such as this one.
[Rust import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126450/rust-import-error) I tried to use imports outlined in the accepted answer which looks something like this.

main.rs

```rust
mod render;
mod db;
mod ark;

//Main loop etc
...
```

ark.rs

```rust
use render;
use db;

//Structs, enums etc
...
```

db.rs

```rust
use render;
use ark;

//DB functions
...
```

render.rs

```rust
use db;
use ark;

//Render functions
...
```

But this structure leads to the following errors.

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `db`
 --> src/render.rs:1:9
  |
1 |     use db;
  |         ^^ no external crate `db`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `ark`
 --> src/render.rs:2:9
  |
2 |     use ark;
  |         ^^^ no external crate `ark`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `render`
 --> src/db.rs:1:9
  |
1 |     use render;
  |         ^^^^^^ no external crate `render`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `ark`
 --> src/db.rs:2:9
  |
2 |     use ark;
  |         ^^^ no external crate `ark`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `render`
 --> src/ark.rs:1:9
  |
1 |     use render;
  |         ^^^^^^ no external crate `render`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `db`
 --> src/ark.rs:2:9
  |
2 |     use db;
  |         ^^ no external crate `db`

...
```

What is the correct method for splitting my main.rs file into 4 smaller files, such that each of the files can use the structs and functions in the other files.

Comment: Your individual files should not have that `pub mod X {` wrapper. The file itself is already a module because of the `mod X;` lines in `main.rs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In main:

```
mod render;
mod db;
mod ark;
```

Then in everything else:

```
use crate::render;
use crate::db;
// ...
```

Comment: Do I need to list every single struct and function at the top of each of the files? If I try something like `use crate::render::*;` it doesn't work. But without it the compiler seems to suggest that I need to add an import each time it encounters a function or struct which is in a different file. In other words is there a way I can import the whole file in one go

Comment: "If I try something like use `crate::render::*;` it doesn't work." - what's the error in this case? If you have `mod render;` in `lib.rs`, this import should work, modulo name conflicts.

Comment: If I put `use crate::ark::*;` at the top of db.rs I get errors like `could not find 'Event' in 'ark'`. if I manually specify each struct/enum/func etc in the file such as  `use crate::ark::{Event, MenuItem};`, then it works fine.

Comment: In hindsight it could be caused by me changing this `Event::Input(event) => match event.code {` to this `ark::Event::Input(event) => match event.code {` when I first tried it. I have since undone that change but I've already manually specified almost all of them. To clarify for others I will try commenting it out and replacing it with the simple version

Comment: If I change `use crate::render::{read_db};` back to `use crate::render;`  I get the error `error[E0425]: cannot find function 'read_db' in this scope` even though the function is public. I'm just going to manually specify everything for now, but if there is anything else I should test let me know.

Comment: @scorch855 You need to specify the last portion of the path you `use`'d. So if you `use crate::render::{read_db};` you need to specify `read_db`, since that's the last portion. If you `use crate::render;` you need to specify `render::read_db`. If you don't `use` anything you need to specify `crate::render::read_db`.